# Oracle enterprise manager cloud control 13c extensibility download agent failed

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am using Oracle enterprise manager cloud control 13c

It has no agent for oracle db 12 for Linux machines and I trie to download it using the extensibility -> self update -> agent software and then downloaded the wanted agent.

However, it returns the following error:

> Downloading file in staging directory
>
> /u01/app/oracle/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/stage/451ce1ed9fe053dce0533a01a8c07780
>
> ... Staging directory cleaned up. Download failed: Exception: Error
> downloading file: Server returned invalid response. Status Code = 200

I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/EMGGP/toc.htm#BABFCBCE) closed bug report, but this is relevant to the golden gate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we had changed the meta like password and did not update it in the oms server interface, i was surprised the cloud control system did not alert specifically...